# Word.Application SaveCopyAs Unknown runtime error: 800A1704

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I wrote a VBScript to convert Word 97-2003 Documents to Word 2016 Documents (I have Microsoft Office 2016 installed on Windows 10 v1709, 64-bit Enterprise).

Here's the minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
Dim Word, DOC, FSO, Dir
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Dir = FSO.GetFolder(".")

Dim FileName
FileName = Dir.Path & "\test.doc"
Set DOC = Word.Documents.Open(FileName)
DOC.SaveCopyAs FileName & "x"
DOC.Close
Word.Quit
```

Open Word, create a blank document and save it as "Word 97-2003 Document" with the file name being `test.doc` and place it under the same directory as the VBScript. Then run the script.

[image: Error Dialog Box]

However, if you slightly modify the above script and try to convert `.xls` to `.xlsx` or `.ppt` to `.pptx`, it works. Actually that code is modified from a fully working PPT to PPTX converter that I wrote earlier. It worked very well without any problems with PowerPoint 2016 on the same system. Another modification to make an XLS to XLSX converter also worked with Excel 2016.

My Google-fu did no useful job, nor did re-installing Office 2016 help. I also tried on 2 other computers with freshly installed Windows 10 v1709 Enterprise and Office 2016 (both 64-bit), and the same error showed up.

Any idea how can I save that as DOCX with the current VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by recording a macro, the following code was generated for saving the word from .doc to .docx extension

```
DOC.SaveAs2 FileName &"x",12,,,,,,,,,,15    'FileFormat = 12; WdSaveFormat =15
```

Comment: I assumed everything was "defaulted". You mean that's the cause for the issue?

Comment: Thanks. `DOC.SaveAs2 FileName & "x", 12` works. No need for the extra commas and the last argument.

Comment: Not really an expert with word. But, yes, all the other parameters are optional and if their values aren't specified, they will get the default values. Find more help on these params [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-saveas2-method-word)

Comment: @iBug That's great

Comment: Looks like I just can't use `SaveCopyAs` on Word. That makes Word really distinctive.

Comment: This is the automation standard that Word adheres to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms221181(v=vs.85).aspx